# laravel deactivate event for update() on model

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, eloquent

When a model of me is updated an event is triggered:

```
protected $events = [
    'updated' => ZoneUpdated::class,
];
```

The event listener which is triggered will create on the model too:

```
public function handle(ZoneUpdated $event)
{
    Zone::find($event->zone->id)->update([
        'updated' => true,
        'valid'   => 'u',
    ]);
}
```

How can I disable the listener to fire a new event, because at the moment this produces an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you still need to keep track of the Model Updated event and still continue to update that Model, you can try to update the Model in in Listener using Fluent

```
public function handle(ZoneUpdated $event)
{
    // assuming table name for Zone Model is "zones" and primary key is "id"
    \DB::table('zones')
        ->where('id', $event->zone->id)
        ->update([
            'updated' => true,
            'valid'   => 'u',
        ]);
}
```

Using fluent should stop the infinite loop as it no longer will execute the update based on the Model Object but directly to the Database via Fluent.

Having said that, I would urge you to rethink how you are using event listener and if this is really what you need.

Comment: Can I understand this as _"directly update from DB call to skip the hassle of model-event triggers"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make sure events only fire on certain conditions, but I find a simpler way to circumvent this would be to use the `updating` event instead of `update`:

```
protected $events = [
    'updating' => ZoneUpdated::class,
];
```